# Get property of Objects in an Array as String

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a **one-line solution** (specific function) you can use to get a specific property of all `Objects` in an `Array` as:

1. a (comma separated) `String`?
2. the sum of all values?

Example data (I know this isn't PHP code but it's an example of how the data looks like):

```
$user1 = { id: 1, name: 'u1', score: 10 }
$user2 = { id: 2, name: 'u2', score: 20 }
$admins = array($user1, $user2);
```

Output I would like:

```
magicalArrayFunction($admins, 'name', ', ');
//SHOULD OUTPUT: "u1, u2"
magicalSumArrayFunction($admins, 'score');
//SHOULD OUTPUT: 30
```

Comment: `$user1 = { id: 1, name: 'u1', score: 10 }`. This syntax is invalid in PHP

Comment: [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) with [`join`](http://php.net/join) or [`array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum) would do.

Comment: @hindmost: It was just a representation of the data... The $user1 object has 'id', 'name' and 'score' as property in this example.

Comment: may be $user1 = array( 'id'=> 1, 'name' => 'u1', 'score' => 10 );

Comment: I would just use `foreach`...no magical functions exist for what you want.

Comment: @mario: Sadly the server is < PHP 5.5, but thanks for the answer! So for those wondering, mario's answer is the correct one.

Comment: There's a userland shim (always a good approach, since you're somewhen gonna use 5.5 anyway) in the manual. Albeit if your list really contained objects, you'd also need `array_map("get_object_vars", $admin)`.

Answer (score 1):

no there is no build in function to get this done, but you can use the `array_sum`, `array_map` and the PHP `implode` Functions to get the work done.

```
function magicalArrayFunction($array)
{
    return implode(',', array_map(function($v){
        return $v['name'];
    }, $array));
}

$usersString = magicalArrayFunction($admins);
echo $usersString;

function magicalSumArrayFunction($array)
{
    return array_sum(array_map(function($v){
        return $v['score'];
    }, $array));
}

$arraySum = magicalSumArrayFunction($admins);
echo $arraySum;
```

just edit the `return $v['name'];` line to your object specific return value. like `return $v->name;`

---

**//edit after comment**

one liner solution

```
$array = ...
$userString = implode(',', array_map(function($v){return $v['name'];}, $array));
$arraySum = array_sum(array_map(function($v){return $v['score'];}, $array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop through your users. Foreach is your friend.

```php
$user1 = json_decode( '{"id":1,"name":"u1","score":10}');
$user2 = json_decode( '{"id":2,"name":"u2","score":20}');
$admins = array($user1, $user2);

$names = array();
$score = 0;
foreach( $admins as $user) {
    $names[] = $user->name;
    $score += $user->score;
}
echo implode( ",", $names) . "\n";
echo $score;
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I was wondering if there was an one-line solution as mentioned...

Comment: You could compress this into a one liner :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution, as you need.. Though, validation for integer value in Sum function is remained to implement.. you can add it manually..

```
$user1 = '{"id":1,"name":"u1","score":10}';
$user2 = '{"id":2,"name":"u2","score":20}';
$admins = array($user1, $user2);

echo magicalArrayFunction($admins, 'name', ', ');
//SHOULD OUTPUT: "u1, u2"
echo "<br>";
echo magicalSumArrayFunction($admins, 'score');
//SHOULD OUTPUT: 30

function magicalArrayFunction($array, $column, $sep = ', ') {
    foreach($array as $jsons){
        $new_Arr[] = json_decode($jsons, true);
    }
    return implode($sep,array_column_custom($new_Arr, $column));
} 
function magicalSumArrayFunction($array, $column){
    foreach($array as $jsons){
        $new_Arr[] = json_decode($jsons, true);
    }
    return array_sum(array_column_custom($new_Arr, $column));
}

function array_column_custom($array, $column){
    foreach($array as $keys=>$inner_array){
        foreach($inner_array as $inner_keys=> $values){
            if($inner_keys == $column){
                $newArr[] = $values;
            }
        }
    }
    return $newArr;
}
```

**Edit: One Liner Solution**

```
$user1 = '{"id":1,"name":"u1","score":10}';
$user2 = '{"id":2,"name":"u2","score":20}';
$admins = array($user1, $user2);

// Fixed column name used here i.e. 'name','score'.. 
$userNames = implode(',', array_map(function($u){$u=json_decode($u, true); return $u['name'];}, $admins));
$totalScore = array_sum(array_map(function($u){ $u=json_decode($u, true); return $u['score'];}, $admins));

// If you need to call function..
echo magicalArrayFunction($admins, 'name', ', ');
echo magicalSumArrayFunction($admins, 'score');
function magicalArrayFunction($array, $column, $sep = ', ') {
    return implode($sep, array_map(function($u,$c){ $u=json_decode($u, true); return $u[$c];}, $array, str_split(str_repeat($column, count($array)),strlen($column)) ));    
} 
function magicalSumArrayFunction($array, $column){
    return array_sum(array_map(function($u,$c){ $u=json_decode($u, true); return $u[$c];}, $array,str_split(str_repeat($column, count($array)),strlen($column))));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I was wondering if there was an one-line solution as mentioned...